# Rolling Average Calculation in Data Canvas Transformation

Tags: spotfire

I have this calculation for my line chart and it works great:

avg([OIL_BBLD]) THEN Avg([Value]) OVER (LastPeriods(90,[Axis.X])) THEN If(Count() OVER (LastPeriods(90,[Axis.X]))=90,[Value],null) as [Cal Day Avg Oil]

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG1SY.png)

enter image description here
But I need to have the output of this rolling average as a column in my table, how would I do this?

I have tried copying this expression into the data canvas tool but its not working as axis.X is unknown which makes sense but Im unsure what I need to substitute into axis.X